# Makefile not linking dll's

Tags: makefile

I am making a game in SDL2 and C++. I use a makefile with mingw32 in visual stuido code. Because I am using SDL2 I want to use the SDL2 dll's. It works with all the dll's in the main project directory but not if I put them in the folder they are supposed to be in.

This is my make file:

```
all:
    g++ -o main main.cpp entity.cpp entity.hpp player.cpp player.hpp -Isrc/Include -Lsrc/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

When I open the .exe that was made with the make command:
[image]
[image]

I do not get any errors when I make the .exe, but when I try to open it this is what I get. As stated above, these problems do not affect me if I have all the dll's in the main directory.

If I change the makefile to contain the directory of the dll's I get errors when trying to make the exe.:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp entity.cpp entity.hpp player.cpp player.hpp -Isrc/Include -Lsrc/lib -lmingw32 -lsrc/lib/SDL2main -lsrc/lib/SDL2 -lsrc/lib/SDL2_image
D:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsrc/lib/SDL2main
D:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsrc/lib/SDL2
D:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsrc/lib/SDL2_image
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: there's no information in here about the problem you're having.  What happens when you try to run this makefile?

Comment: This makefile works when I have my dll's right next to my cpp files in the project folder, but not if I put them in the src/lib folder

Comment: You haven't defined what "doesn't work" actually means.  It's like calling up your mechanic and saying "my car won't go".  Please cut and paste (with formatting) the command you typed and the error messages you got back.

Comment: So, you don't see any errors when you run `make`, but you do see errors when you try to run the program that `make` generates?  These are important facts to include in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the error message into it, with proper formatting, as I requested above.  It's hard to read unformatted error messages in comments.  Does the file `src/lib/SDL2_ttf.lib` exist?  If not, that's the problem.